# How to encrypt transmissions between Elasticsearch cluster nodes with TLS without using Shield

Tags: encryption, elasticsearch

Elastic provides the ability to encrypted traffic between cluster nodes with Shield: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/ssl-tls.html

However, Shield is quite expensive for our organization and we're looking for a way to achieve TLS encryption between nodes without using Shield.

Is there a way? If possible, I'd be looking for a way to do this in both version 2.4 and 5.0.